# How to make Google Script run for all users of the Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have built a Sheet that uses the script below to move rows from one tab to another, based on the selection made in a column. For example, if the selection in this column is changed to CLOSED, the entire row gets moved to the CLOSED tab.  If it is changed to DEAD, it gets moved to the DEAD tab.

The problem though, is it only works when I do it, but not when any of the other collaborators change the cell.  Here is the code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var activatedSheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var activatedCell = ss.getActiveSelection();
  var activatedCellRow = activatedCell.getRow();
  var activatedCellColumn = activatedCell.getColumn();
  var activatedCellValue = activatedCell.getValue();

  var preclosingTrackerSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PRECLOSING"); // source sheet
  var closingTrackerSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CLOSING"); // target sheet
  var closedTrackerSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CLOSED FILES"); // target sheet
  var deadTrackerSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DEAD FILES"); // target sheet

  // if the value in column AG is "2-Closing", and you are in the PRECLOSING Sheet, MOVE the row to CLOSING sheet
  if (activatedSheetName == preclosingTrackerSheet.getName() && activatedCellColumn == 33 && activatedCellValue == "2-Closing") {
    // insert a new row at the second row of the target sheet
    closingTrackerSheet.insertRows(2,1);

    // copy the entire source row to the second row of target sheet
    var rangeToMove = preclosingTrackerSheet.getRange(/*startRow*/ activatedCellRow, /*startColumn*/ 1, /*numRows*/ 1, /*numColumns*/ preclosingTrackerSheet.getMaxColumns());
    rangeToMove.moveTo(closingTrackerSheet.getRange("A2"));

    // delete row from source sheet
    preclosingTrackerSheet.deleteRows(activatedCellRow,1);

  }

  // if the value in column AG is "CLOSED", and you are in the PRECLOSING Sheet, MOVE the row to CLOSED sheet
  if (activatedSheetName == preclosingTrackerSheet.getName() && activatedCellColumn == 33 && activatedCellValue == "3-Closed") {
    // insert a new row at the second row of the target sheet
    closedTrackerSheet.insertRows(2,1);
    // move the entire source row to the third row of target sheet
    var rangeToMove = preclosingTrackerSheet.getRange(/*startRow*/ activatedCellRow, /*startColumn*/ 1, /*numRows*/ 1, /*numColumns*/ preclosingTrackerSheet.getMaxColumns());
    rangeToMove.moveTo(closedTrackerSheet.getRange("A2"));

    // delete row from source sheet
    preclosingTrackerSheet.deleteRows(activatedCellRow,1);
  }


  // if the value in column AG is "DEAD", and you are in the PRECLOSING Sheet, MOVE the row to DEAD sheet
  if (activatedSheetName == preclosingTrackerSheet.getName() && activatedCellColumn == 33 && activatedCellValue == "x-Dead") {
    // insert a new row at the second row of the target sheet
    deadTrackerSheet.insertRows(2,1);
    // move the entire source row to the third row of target sheet
    var rangeToMove = preclosingTrackerSheet.getRange(/*startRow*/ activatedCellRow, /*startColumn*/ 1, /*numRows*/ 1, /*numColumns*/ preclosingTrackerSheet.getMaxColumns());
    rangeToMove.moveTo(deadTrackerSheet.getRange("A2"));

    // delete row from source sheet
    preclosingTrackerSheet.deleteRows(activatedCellRow,1);
  }

  // if the value in column AG is "PRECLOSING", and you are in the CLOSING Sheet, MOVE the row to PRECLOSING sheet
  if (activatedSheetName == closingTrackerSheet.getName() && activatedCellColumn == 33 && activatedCellValue == "1-Preclosing") {
    // insert a new row at the second row of the target sheet
    preclosingTrackerSheet.insertRows(2,1);

    // move the entire source row to the third row of target sheet
    var rangeToMove = closingTrackerSheet.getRange(/*startRow*/ activatedCellRow, /*startColumn*/ 1, /*numRows*/ 1, /*numColumns*/ closingTrackerSheet.getMaxColumns());
    rangeToMove.moveTo(preclosingTrackerSheet.getRange("A2"));

    // delete row from source sheet
    closingTrackerSheet.deleteRows(activatedCellRow,1);
  }

  // if the value in column AG is "CLOSED", and you are in the CLOSING Sheet, MOVE the row to CLOSED sheet
  if (activatedSheetName == closingTrackerSheet.getName() && activatedCellColumn == 33 && activatedCellValue == "3-Closed") {
    // insert a new row at the second row of the target sheet
    closedTrackerSheet.insertRows(2,1);
    // move the entire source row to the third row of target sheet
    var rangeToMove = closingTrackerSheet.getRange(/*startRow*/ activatedCellRow, /*startColumn*/ 1, /*numRows*/ 1, /*numColumns*/ closingTrackerSheet.getMaxColumns());
    rangeToMove.moveTo(closedTrackerSheet.getRange("A2"));

    // delete row from source sheet
    closingTrackerSheet.deleteRows(activatedCellRow,1);
  }


  // if the value in column AG is "DEAD", and you are in the CLOSING Sheet, MOVE the row to DEAD sheet
  if (activatedSheetName == closingTrackerSheet.getName() && activatedCellColumn == 33 && activatedCellValue == "x-Dead") {
    // insert a new row at the second row of the target sheet
    deadTrackerSheet.insertRows(2,1);
    // move the entire source row to the third row of target sheet
    var rangeToMove = closingTrackerSheet.getRange(/*startRow*/ activatedCellRow, /*startColumn*/ 1, /*numRows*/ 1, /*numColumns*/ closingTrackerSheet.getMaxColumns());
    rangeToMove.moveTo(deadTrackerSheet.getRange("A2"));

    // delete row from source sheet
    closingTrackerSheet.deleteRows(activatedCellRow,1);
  }  

}
```

How do I tell the script to run for all users on this Sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Do you care if the function runs as the editors or is it fine just running as you?

To run just as you, the function needs setup on an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that executes as you and uses up your processing quota. Any editor can then activate it without needing to authorize it with this route. Resources >> Current project's triggers >> Add new - link >> myFunction >> from spreadsheet >> onEdit >> Save.

Would suggest renaming the onEdit() to your own function name in that case so it doesn't fire twice when you're editing.

To run as the actual editors and not on behalf of you then they will each need to, in some way, authorize the script upfront first. That can happen via a click of a custom menu item, click of a button in a sidebar Add-on, on installation of an Add-on from the Add-on store or by running a function manually through the script editor. Your existing onEdit() [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) will then fire as them.

Comment: I would like every person who can edit to be able to make the change to this column, and the script fire when they do.  How would I make a button that they only need to click once (these aren't the brightest people in the world) so the script would work for them?

Comment: just setup the installed trigger if you don't trust them to be able to click a button first

Comment: So I followed the instructions and setup the trigger, but after testing it with another user's account, the row is not moving.  What is the "button" option you were referring to?

Comment: is it moving under your account? you'll also have to change `var ss = e.source`

Comment: Yes Bryan, when I make the selection, the script is moving the row as expected. However, when other users make the selection, the row does not move.